# Is it possible to expose an API for my own WebSite ... but use oAuth for the api authentication?

Tags: .net, api, authentication, oauth, basic-authentication

currently I expose an Api for my website. Works great .. and i use *Basic Authentication* to authenticate users to get access to the data.

eg.

```
http://www.MyWebSite.com  <-- main site.
http://api.MyWebSite.com  <-- my api website.
```

sample api *RESTful* url

```
http://user1:pass1@api.MyWebSite.com/games?type=battlefield2
```

(yes yes i know browsers stop people from putting in user1:pass1 (Basic Auth) into the url directly .. cause of security . but it's to highlight that we're using Basic Auth)).

**So .. how can i do this with oAuth?**

Answer (score 0):

You might consider looking at these resources to get rolling with OAuth in an ASP.NET application or with WCF services:

- http://oauth.net/code/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/11/14/oauth-channel-for-wcf-restful-services.aspx